# Company page is not German

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, advertising, localization

This localized ad displays *Company page anzeigen* at the button.

[image: ad]

While *anzeigen* is German, *Company page* is not.

It could be  *Stellenanzeige öffnen* or *Stellenbeschreibung anzeigen*

Answer (score -2):

This is by design. For certain terms such as *Company Page* or *Employer Branding*, we've decided not to use a German translation, but to keep the English expression instead.

Look at [this](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/products/company-pages) page to see a few examples of those terms used in context.

Comment: While this is ok for "complete" phrases, it makes absolutely no sense to mix languages in a single phrase or sentence.

Comment: מצטער but I agree with @juergend - this only cause בלבול. :)

Comment: Re mixing: this is for consistency. It would be confusing to use a *different* translation for the same thing in short phrases vs. entire paragraphs. 

That being said, of course we could *generally* give preference to localized term such as "Unternehmensseite" over English terms such as "Company Page" and then use those consistently across the site.

We hear the downvotes, stand by for an update.