# Stack Overflow Cities careers View company page button is not localised

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

Go to [Stack Overflow Careers cities](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities)

Scroll down to the bottom of the page and select either French or German as your language.

Now pick a city e.g [Seattle](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities/seattle?f=e)

Scroll down a little to find the the View company page button of the Featured Company is still in English.

[image: View Company Page]

There is a [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247925/company-page-is-not-german) pertaining to adverts but that's about the German language only. In French the words "company page" are normally translated on the careers site c.f. the bottom of the [Cities home page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities) where this

[image: Create a free company page]

becomes this

[image: Create a free company page in French]

Comment: Will be fixed with our next localization refresh (next couple of days).